# How to print something on the basis of data (input) type?

Tags: python

I want to print different things when `input()` gets different data types. I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

f = input("Please enter a number: ")

if f == type(int):
    print("That's good")
elif f == type(str):
    print("That isn't a number.")
else:
    print("BrainOverflow")
```

This script always returns the else part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to do type checking in python, so you can try something like this:

```
f = input("Please enter a number: ")
try:
    f=int(f)
    print("That's good")
except ValueError:
    print("That isn't a number.")
```

or :

```
f = input("Please enter a number: ")
if f.isdigit():
    print("That's good")
else:
    print("That isn't a number.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Does not make any sense that you are trying since the result of the input() call is always
a string. Your code needs some dedicated methods for checking if the string is representation of an integer or not. See

[Python: Check if a string represents an int, Without using Try/Except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)