# How to repeat in python

Tags: python

```
sides=int(input("Please enter the amount of sides on the dice: "))
times=int(input("Please enter the number of times you want to repeat: "))
```

I want to repeat those two lines until the user input an int number for each request.
Thanks

Comment: A good place to start would be to learn about [while loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop). Then, take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except

Comment: Take a look at some tutorials and [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), and report back when you get stuck. You won't really get the most out of Stack Overflow until you've learned the basic foundations of the language.

Comment: something similar to do-while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading loosely,

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:    # wasn't an int
            pass

sides = get_int("Please enter the amount of sides on the dice: ")
times = get_int("Please enter the number of times you want to repeat: ")
```

but if you strictly want to repeat *both* statements until *both* get an int value,

```
while True:
    s1 = input("Please enter the amount of sides on the dice: ")
    s2 = input("Please enter the number of times you want to repeat: ")
    try:
        sides = int(s1)
        times = int(s2)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sides=0;times=0
while(sides == 0 and times == 0):
    sides=int(input("Please enter the amount of sides on the dice: "))
    times=int(input("Please enter the number of times you want to repeat: "))
```

Comment: It return error and I have to reload the code again. I want to repeat those two lines until the user input an int number for each request.

Comment: it's returning an error because you're telling the code to `int()` whatever the user gives it. What happens if it's not a number? Python will throw an error. Read about [`try/catch`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/errors.html) statements to catch that error and continue with execution