# Checking for a draw in Tic Tac Toe [Python]

Tags: python

I have this Python program that plays tic tac toe between two human players. If Player A or Player B ever wins, it is announced and the program terminates. However, if the program ends in a draw, it will keep requesting user input.

I'm not sure how to check for a draw. Does it have to be within the while loop or does it require it's own separate function?

```
import sys

## Define and create tic tac toe gameboard
board = range(0,9)

def show_board():
    print board[0], '|', board[1], '|', board[2]
    print '---------'
    print board[3], '|', board[4], '|', board[5]
    print '---------'
    print board[6], '|', board[7], '|', board[8]

# Function used to check for winner
def line(char, box1, box2, box3):
    if board[box1] == char and board[box2] == char and board[box3] == char:
        return True

# Function used to automate process for checking every possible way to win
def all(char):
    # Horizontal check
    if line(char, 0, 1, 2):
        return True
    if line(char, 3, 4, 5):
        return True
    if line(char, 6, 7, 8):
        return True
    # Vertical check
    if line(char, 0, 3, 6):
        return True
    if line(char, 1, 4, 7):
        return True
    if line(char, 2, 5, 8):
        return True
    # Diagnol check
    if line(char, 0, 4, 8):
        return True
    if line(char, 2, 4, 6):
        return True

show_board()

# Initial while loop will ask for player A input and show the board as well
# check conditions to see whether or not player A wins. If player A wins,
# the program will terminate so it does not ask for player B input after.
while True:
    player_a = int(raw_input('Player A, please select a spot that is not taken \
(0-8): '))
    # Checks for empty spot and places an 'X' if it exists, otherwise
    # asks again.
    if board[player_a] != 'X' and board[player_a] != 'O':
        board[player_a] = 'X'
        show_board()
        # Check to see if Player A wins.
        if all('X') == True:
            print "Player A wins."
            sys.exit()
            break;

# While loop to ask for player B input and display the board as well as check
# the conditions as to whether or not player B wins. If player B wins, the
# program will terminate so it does not ask for player A input after.
        while True:
            player_b = int(raw_input('Player B, please select a spot that is \
not taken (0-8): '))
            # Checks for empty spot and places an 'O' if it exists, otherwise
            # asks again.
            if board[player_b] != 'O' and board[player_b] != 'X':
                board[player_b] = 'O'
                # Check to see if Player B wins.
                if all('O') == True:
                    show_board()
                    print "Player B wins."
                    sys.exit()
                    break;

                break;

    show_board()
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Aside: `all` is a bad choice for a function name, because it is also the name of a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

Without extensively going through the code, I can tell you that a draw is occurs after 9 turns, and only if both Player A and B do not receive a win on that final turn. For your simple program, what I would do is create a global variable called ELAPSED_TURNS or something of the sort, that increments each time a player enters a character, and then after checking both of the players' win conditions, and if there is no win, check ELAPSED_TURNS. If it is equal to 9, then the game must be a draw.

Comment: I guess I am having difficulty with the placement. I'd initialize turns = 0 before the while loop. And then I'd increase the turn counter by 1 all the way at the end? However, trying this breaks the code and it just keeps asking for player B input.

Comment: Initialize turns = 0 at the very start of your program, and increment turns if neither A or B has won that round, and then do the check for turn number 9.

Comment: Your while loops are a little confusing, but if you know how your program is structured, this should be quite the easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function that does what you want.

```
def is_tie():
    for position in board:
        if isinstance(position, int):
            return False
    print "The game is a tie."
    sys.exit()
```

Put a call to `is_tie()` directly after both while loops like this...

```
while True:
    is_tie()    
    player_a = int(raw_input(...

while True:
    is_tie()    
    player_b = int(raw_input(...
```

If this is a learning exercise for you I would recommend refactoring your code to find a way wrap all your logic blocks into functions and getting everything to flow without the use of `sys.exit()`.  Doing so will increase the readability and make it easier to splice in new logic.

EDIT to your comment:

You can create an integer test function using just try / except statements like this...

```
def is_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Credit here:  [Python: Check if a string represents an int, Without using Try/Except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Your `is_tie()` function would then look like this:

```
def is_tie():
    for position in board:
        if is_int(position):
            return False
    print "The game is a tie."
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Is there a "simpler" version of isinstance? I've not learned about that function yet so I don't want to include things I don't know.