# How to validate a users input to Numbers only?

Tags: python

I need help validating the input from the (random) questions I ask to make sure that the users input is only a number, rather than letters or any other random character. Also along with the validation there should be an error message notifying the user theyve done something wrong as well as repeat their chance to do the question.

So far the section of my code I need validating is the following:

```
def quiz():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)

    ops = {'+': operator.add,'-': operator.sub,'*': operator.mul}

    keys = list(ops.keys())
    opt = random.choice(keys)
    operation = ops[opt]  

    answer = operation(x, y)

    print ("\nWhat is {} {} {}?".format(x, opt, y))
    userAnswer= int(input("\nYour answer: "))

    if userAnswer != answer: #validate users answer to correct answer
        print ("\nIncorrect. The right answer is",answer,"")
        print ("\n============= 8 =============")
        return False
    else:
        print("\nCorrect!")
        print ("\n============= 8 =============")
        return True

for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
    if quiz():
        score +=1

print("\n{}: You got {}/{} questions correct.".format(name, score, questions,))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Answer (score 2):

Use `try...except`:

```
while True:
    userAnswer = input("\nYour answer: ")
    try:
       val = float(userAnswer)
       break
    except ValueError:
       print("That's not a number!")
```

If you want only integers, use `int` instead of `float`.

Comment: Thanks!, I will try to integrate this to my code now.

Comment: replace this line `userAnswer= int(input("\nYour answer: "))` with my code

Comment: ahh u edited it thanks, i was having some problems trying to asapt the code to mine, ill try this. and yes i will mark as Answered. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, This works, it validates the input, however, before the code would say wheather or not the user got their answer Right ot Wrong, need to work on that. any suggestions before i get it? @bigOTHER

Comment: @MysticMods dont print anything inside `quiz()`,   get her value by calling it and print it when you want

Comment: @bigOTHER: use `while True:` and `break` instead of `R`.

Comment: The validation works, thanks, however in terms of the purpose of my code it doesnt exactly fit in, i need to ask 10 questions and also say weather or not they got the answer right or wrong, if they did get it wrong then the code tells them the right answer, and then moves onto the next question...? Im just going to try a few more things...

Comment: @MysticMods you made a question, I answered it.. if you have other questions, ask them and someone willanswer them. this is how it works in stackoverflow, we dont have to do the whole code for you.

Comment: its ok thanks, ive understood how exactly to validate inputs now thanks to your help. thanks again. @bigOTHER

Answer (score 1):

in Single line :

```
assert input('Enter Number: ').isdigit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use function validate integer input:

```
def int_validation(user_Input):
    try:
        val = int(user_Input)
    except ValueError:
        print(user_Input,' not an integer!')
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be good to make a function to accept your input. This can then keep prompting the user until a valid number is entered:

```
def get_number(prompt):
    while True:
        try: 
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")
```

You can then change your input line as follows:

```
userAnswer = get_number("\nYour answer: ")
```