# unexpected function return different type / number only checker

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a quick and simple function to check if an entered value is an int/bool. I've had a quick look around and even the solution elsewhere comes to the same issue.

I have this in my test script and it seems to work, but when copying the exact code to my main program it will return the first value entered (say I entered hello instead of a number it will exit with "hello" after typing a number and save that to file).

Is there something with a function calling another function that causes it to fail?

I can post my actual code later, there's a lot of calls in it so it may be quite long. Will try with these short examples first and if we can't figure I can post the long one.

```
#option 1
import json

with open("settings.json", "r") as f:
    pref_file = json.load(f)

def float_check(t):
    if t.isdigit():
        global prompt
        prompt = float(t)
        return #I have tried 'return prompt' too
    else:
        prompt = input ("Enter numerical value only:\n")
        float_check(prompt)

prompt = input ("Enter a number: ")

float_check(prompt)

#I'm saving the value to JSON file.
#\\ settings.json
#{
#    "o2_percent": 0.0
#}

pref_file["o2_percent"] = prompt
with open("settings.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(pref_file, f, indent=4)
```

In option 2 I tried calling a function from a function as I thought that was the issue. But this also seems to work.

```
#option 2
import json
def num_check(t):
    if t.isdigit():
        global prompt
        prompt = float(t) 
        pref_file["o2_percent"] = prompt
        with open("settings.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(pref_file, f, indent=4)
        runit()
    else:
        prompt = input ("Enter numerical numer only:\n")
        num_check(prompt)

def runit():
    prompt = input ("enter a number: ")
    num_check(prompt)

runit()
```

I found this solution ([How to validate a users input to Numbers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298668/how-to-validate-a-users-input-to-numbers-only-python)) and have adapted it a little but I'm having the exact same issue - my main code will return the first value entered not the number when exiting the loop.

enter number: hello
enter number: elephant
enter number: why
enter number: 5
saves value to settings.json "hello"

Also why does the first print return float as expected but the second is an str, I've done no further processing? I'm new to all this - is there some jenky thing if using variables in a function even if declared global?

```
def mk_float(answer):
    while True:
        try:
           answer = float(answer)
           print (type(answer)) #returns float
           break
        except ValueError:
           answer = input ("Enter number!")

answer = input ("number: ")

mk_float(answer)

print (type(answer)) #returns int
```

I'm about ready to table flip.

**Edit**
This was my comment that I deleted, as Prune pointed out its a seperate question. But will throw it on the edit so people know what it was in reference to.

```
def t_check(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            prompt = int(prompt)
            return int(prompt)
            break
        except ValueError:
            prompt = input ("Enter a number only: ")        
            continue


prompt = input ("enter something: ")
t_check(prompt)

print (prompt)
print (type(prompt))
```

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. _is there some jenky thing if using variables in a function even if declared global_ The use of global variables, and names which shadow each other, can't be helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface problem is because, when you repeat the request for valid input, instead of using a simple [loop-until-valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) approach, you use recursion.  As you wind back up the stack on final return, you can easily get a reversal of the data you want.

The next problem is using global variables.  Use parameters for input to your function; return the result.  Global variables usually indicate poor design.

Note that `print` returns `None`, not a float.

Finally, you should trace your program's execution, as well as intermediate results, using simple `print` commands.  This is the simplest and most immediately effective debugging tool.

Does that help you get going?

Comment: Hey Prune (not sure how to tag you) thanks for the reply.If you look at the 3rd case with the try thats what I was trying (no pun intended). I will look more into the one you linked and see if I can get it to work a bit better. Just confuses me as it works in one code and blows up in another. Only difference is one is in an if statement.

Comment: This looks like another question, not a comment.  At the very least, edit this into your question, not here.  As you can see, comments *really* suck for posting code -- especially for Python's white-space semantics.

Comment: I deleted the previous comment - yeah it was a disaster of a comment - I'm brand new here (and returning to programming after 20 years off) still figuring out the kinks, so apologies for being all noob. That said I think I've figured it all out. My god *hugest facepalm* I was calling the function wrong... I'd call the function then I'd try use the return on a seperate line. This 'pref_file["o2_percent"] = float_check(entered)' works perfectly! Thanks for all the help. I'm using the while true loop going forward.

Comment: Understood.  Remember, we've all been you at some point.  Even Ada Byron Lovelace had to *learn* programming, even if she had to invent it first.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I can help with the *json* part of your code, however you may use this function to ask the user to input a number (float or int) :

```py
def input_number():
    try:
        return float(input ("Enter numerical value only:\n"))
    except ValueError:
        return input_number()
```

When the user input something, `input_number` will try to return the input as a float (which cover the `int` type).
If the conversion to float fails, a ValueError will be catch and `input_number` will ask the user to enter the value again.

In your *very* specific case you may do `pref_file["o2_percent"] = input_number()`

**Edit:**

Looking at Prune's answer, recursion might not be the best good solution. ^_^

Comment: Fortunately the JSON is actually working fine! Your idea to call directly may remove a further couple of lines as I've been calling the input request before and passing in the variable into the checker. I'll give this a try. Thanks for the suggestion :)