# How to deal with the td tag whose colspan == ''?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from html source using BeautifulSoup. This is the source

```
<td class="advisor" colspan="">
```

Here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all('td')

for td in tds:
    if td["colspan"] == '':
        col = 0
    else:
        col = int(td["colspan"])
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I know this error means '' cannot be transformed to integer, but why doesn't my 'if' work? I think this situation should go to

```
col = 0
```

rather than

```
col = int(td["colspan"])
```

Comment: Can you do `if td["colspan"].strip() == '':` and see if that helps?

Comment: Could that include `A,B,C,D,E,F`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh It doesn't work. Can you tell me what is strip()? I have not seen it before in the document. Thank you :)

Comment: @lan I have check the page source of it. It does not contain any string or char but ''. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the url?

Comment: @MartinEvans Here you go: https://secure.wasatchfunds.com/Our-Funds/Portfolio-Details.aspx?fund=waigx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use exception handling as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <td class="advisor" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="advisor" colspan=""></td>
    <td class="advisor" colspan="x"></td>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all('td')

for td in tds:
    try:
        col = int(td["colspan"])
    except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
        col = 0

    print(col)
```

This would display the following:

```
2
0
0
```

Tested using Python 3.4.3

Comment: I've tried the above script on the whole html for the url and it seems to work fine. It produces many 0s, with a couple of 2s. What version of Python and BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I also get all colspan value and the result is same as yours. It is really weird that if did not work...
My python version is 3.5.1 and BS4

Comment: Use `import bs4; print(bs4.__version__)` to display the version, I am using `4.3.2`.

Comment: I know why... This is totally my fault... I find other place also trying to assign td["colspan"]... Deeply sorry for my stupid!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having error due to wrong input type, you could check if the argument is really integer first before you proceed:

```
def check_int(s):
    if s = '' or s is None
        return False
    st = str(s)
    if st[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return st[1:].isdigit()
    return st.isdigit()

for td in tds:
    if check_int(td["colspan"]):
        col = int(td["colspan"])
    else:
        col = 0
```

Or, using ternary operation:

```
for td in tds:
    col = int(td["colspan"]) if check_int(td["colspan"]) else 0
```

Edit: some [good materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) to do int checking without try-except.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally found that it is my fault! I know why it didn't work!! Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the value of var `col` is allways `""`, then check if it's true.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all('td')

for td in tds:
    col = 0
    if td["colspan"].isdigit():
        col = int(td["colspan"])
```

Comment: Try do put some print at the value to debug.

Comment: I print all colspan value and I pretty sure it is '', so it is really weird that the 'if' didn't work..