# Split() that recognizes the types

Tags: python, types

I have a phrase like this:

```
a='Hello I have 4 ducks'
```

and I apply `str.split` to this, so I now I have

```
>>> a.split()
['Hello','I','have','4','ducks'].
```

the problem is that every `a.split()[i]` is a string, but I need the program to recognize that the 4 is an integer. I need this to know which position the first integer is in, so I do this:

```
if(isinstance(a[i], float) or isinstance(a[i], int)):
    punt=k
```

but every `a[i]` is a string.

Can I do something that makes my program recognize the integers inside this list?

Comment: Have you looked into the other string methods? `str.isdigit` will probably be helpful. Or could you `try` the conversion to integer and handle failures on things like `'ducks'`?

Comment: So, there is a metod that acts like split() but recognizes the type of every part? Does str.isdigit do that? Thank you

Comment: No, there isn't. You will have to implement that functionality yourself, but there are helpful methods to do it relatively easily.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Seems like a reasonable concept to me...

Comment: @JeffG the fact that it's received a cavalcade of crap answers in a few minutes suggests that it's the kind of thing the OP should have worked on themselves.

Comment: Thank you everyone! stack overflow teaches better than the teachers, and free...you all good people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
demo_list = ['Hello','I','have','4','ducks']
i=0
for temp in demo_list:
    print temp
    if temp.isdigit():
        print "This is digit"
        print "It is present at location - ", i
    i=i+1
```

Output:
This is digit.

It is present at location -  3

Comment: Thank you! this one function perfectly!

Comment: Note that this would be much simpler with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the output you wish, thus I am not sure whether this is what you want, yet it works:

```
a='Hello I have 4 ducks'
a=a.split()
ints=[]
strings=[]
for part in a: 
    try: 
        ints.append(int(part))
    except:
        strings.append(part)

ints,strings
```

gives:

```
([4], ['Hello', 'I', 'have', 'ducks'])
```

If you want to have a list of types, then you can modify like this:

```
types = []
for part in a:
    try:
        int(part)
        types.append('int')
    except:
        types.append('string')

types
```

which gives:

types

```
['string', 'string', 'string', 'int', 'string']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own version of `split()`. Here i named it `my_split()`.

```
def my_split(astring):
    return [find_type(x) for x in astring.split()]


def find_type(word):
    try:
        word_type = int(word)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            word_type = float(word)
        except ValueError:
            word_type = word
    return word_type

a = 'Hello I have 4 ducks weighing 3.5 kg each'

split_type = [x for x in my_split(a)]
print(split_type)
#['Hello', 'I', 'have', 4, 'ducks', 'weighing', 3.5, 'kg', 'each']
print([type(x) for x in my_split(a)])
#[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]

for i, word in enumerate(split_type):
    if type(word) == int:
        print('Integer found at position {:d}'.format(i + 1))
# Returns: 'Integer found at position 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` won't do this because it is specific to strings.

However you can post-process the output from `split` to check whether each element of its output could be cast to an integer or not, [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1265665/850883). Something like:

```
def maybeCoerceInt(s):
    try: 
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

tokens = a.split()
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    tokens[i] = maybeCoerceInt(tokens[i])
```

Which produces

```
>>> print(tokens)
['Hello', 'I', 'have', 4, 'ducks']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use isdigit function

```
a='Hello I have 4 ducks'
i=0
for  x in a.split():
  i+=1
  if x.isdigit():
     print "Element:"+x
     print "Position:"+i
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably using exception is the best way. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)). Other methods like `isdigit` do not work with negative numbers.

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Also note:

```
float('NaN')
nan
```

Then you could use:

```
if is_number(a[i]):
    punt=k
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` function to do it, here is my anwser:

```
a = 'Hello I have 4 ducks weighing 3 kg each'
a = a.split()
print a

for i in a:
    try:
        if isinstance(eval(i), int):
            print "the index of {i} is {index}".format(i=i, index=a.index(i))
    except NameError:
        pass

# the results
['Hello', 'I', 'have', '4', 'ducks', 'weighing', '3', 'kg', 'each']
the index of 4 is 3
the index of 3 is 6
```