# Asserting if a string is a valid int

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, assert

I'm new to TDD, and I ran into a situation while trying to write a test.

My func:

```
def nonce():
    return str(int(1000 * time.time()))
```

I've written a test for it - and while it does what I want, it seems like there should be something in the `unittest` module to handle this?:

```
def test_nonce_returns_an_int_as_string(self):
    n = 'abc'  # I want it to deliberately fail
    self.assertIsInstance(n, str)
    try:
        int(n)
    except ValueError:
        self.fail("%s is not a stringified integer!" % n)
```

**Is there a way to assert this, without `try/except`?**

I have found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except), but the answers do not offer usage of `assert` afaict.

What bothers me especially, is that my `failed test` message is not as pretty and clutter free as opposed to using a pure `unittest.TestCase` methods.

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/bitex/tests/client_tests.py", line 39, in test_restapi_nonce
    int(n)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//git/bitex/tests/client_tests.py", line 41, in test_restapi_nonce
    self.fail("%s is not a stringified integer!" % n)
AssertionError: a is not a stringified integer!
```

Comment: The message is there for debugging your tests; if one exception is raised in the context of handling another, you *usually* want to know about this.

Comment: *"the answers do not offer usage of `assert` afaict"* - what makes you say that? All of them can trivially be adapted into a test - `self.assertTrue(n.isdigit())`, for example.

Comment: Not stopping to think about what it says in the answer makes me say that. You're right. shucks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `n.strip().isdigit()` then, as `int()` will strip the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the assertion *outside* the exception handler; that way Python won't connect the `AssertionError` exception to the `ValueError` being handled:

```
try:
    intvalue = int(n)
except ValueError:
    intvalue = None

 self.assertIsNotNone(intvalue)
```

or test for *digits* instead:

```
self.assertTrue(n.strip().isdigit())
```

Note that that'll only work for integer strings without a sign. A leading `+` or `-` is acceptable to `int()` but not to `str.isdigit()`. But for your specific example, using `str.isdigit()` would suffice.