# Converting GET request parameter to int ... if it is numeric

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

lets say i'm showing some data to user  , i want user to be able to perform some sort of filtering on a numeric field in the database  using a `GET` form so i have something like this

```
code = request.GET.get('code')
condition = {} 
if( code is not None and int(code) > 0 ):
  condition['code'] = int(code)

Somemodel.objects.filter(**condition)
```

but this works only if i code contains a number otherwise i get  this error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

so what is the pythonic way to handle this problem ? should i use `try/except` block? i perfer to handle this in the same `if` statement considering i might add other filters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265665/1005215

Comment: Any reason you're not using Django's builtin forms/validation to process the `request.GET` here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`isnumeric` could check if `code` can be *cast* to `int` and also check that `code` is positive (when converted to an integer) thus replacing `int(code) > 0`:

```
if code is not None and code.isnumeric():
    condition['code'] = int(code)
```

Comment: isnumeric() expects a unicode string?                                                        As i am getting AttributeError for "22" but working fine for u"22".

Comment: @SunilLulla With that Python 3.x tag, I would assume this should work for all strings (which are unicode by default). For Python 2, you could use `isdigit`.

Comment: in python 2.x i prefer `type()` for checking int and other datatypes, is that the wrong way of checking?

Comment: @SunilLulla You cant use `type` to check for `int` in this case, since `code` is a string. But generally, you should consider using `isinstance` which handles inheritance.

Comment: This worked for me, is envolved int()

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Django form with one or more IntegerFields; they do this conversion for you, then you can get the result from `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

This function convert GET params to python numeric/bool accordingly:

```
def convert_params_to_int_or_bool(params):
    for k, v in params.items():
        if v.isnumeric():
            params[k] = int(v)
        if v == 'false':
            params[k] = False
        if v == 'true':
            params[k] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more pythonic way using try/except block:

```
try:
    condition["code"] = int(code)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score -5):

The reason you are getting this error because int() expects the value in number it can be in the form string but it should be a number like "22","33" etc are valid .

But in your case you are passing empty that's why its raising an error. You can achieve your desired output using type(), it helps you in checking the type of number

So the modified code is

```
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    condition = {} 
    if( code is not None and type(code) == int ):
           condition['code'] = int(code)

    Somemodel.objects.filter(**condition)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Except `type(code)` will never be a type `int` at that stage... it'll always be a string that can be empty or otherwise may or may not be a valid int...

Comment: You can apply other checks after the above check like validating a numeric field etc and  could you please elaborate your conditions?