# Break a math expression up into a list of its parts, separating the numbers from the operators

Tags: python

I tried:

```
tokens = [t.strip() for t in re.split(r'((?:-?\d+)|[+\-*/()])', exp)]  
return [t for t in tokens if t != '']
```

But it gets the wrong result:

```
Expected :[3, '+', -4, '*', 5]

Actual   :['3', '+', '-4', '*', '5']
```

Comment: Please take some time reading about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `[int(t) for t in tokens if t.isdigit() else t]`

Comment: @alfasin `isdigit` will fail negative numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Check if a string represents an int, Without using Try/Except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you're right: `[int(t) for t in tokens if re.match(r'^-?\d+$', t) else t]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the items in the `list` to `int`s where appropriate

```
def try_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Then in your function, you can apply this to all the items in the return list

```
return [try_int(t) for t in tokens if t != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop without the syntactic sugar. Convert the str of the integers to int using string method `isdigit()`.

Example:

```
>>> "4".isdigit()
>>> True
```

Comment: Try `'-4'.isdigit()`