# PYTHON: how to make a list with both chars and ints?

Tags: python

I currently have a file that's being read and making every line into a list. The file looks like this:

```
A  11   1
B  12   2
C  11   2
```

It's easy to make a list using `split()`

```
['A', '11', '1']
```

But how do I make a list that contains both chars and ints such that I get this below:

```
['A', 11, 1]
```

would be grateful for some help!

Comment: There's probably some fancy way, but you could just use some for loops to test for ints and replace if needed

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except

Comment: Is it always ints in the same columns?

Comment: ah thank you all for the help. this really warmed my heart to see a lot of constructive help; this is my first stackoverflow question and first python class. very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.isdigit` check as the conditional expression condition to get the digits to make `int`s:

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in line.split()]
```

As e.g. `'-1'.isdigit()` would returns `False`, we can use `re` to do string matching:

```
rcomp = re.compile(r'^[+-]?\d+$')
[int(i) if rcomp.search(i) else i for i in str_.split()]
```

e.g:

```
In [59]: str_ = 'A 2 3'

In [60]: [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in str_.split()]
Out[60]: ['A', 2, 3]

In [61]: str_ = 'A -3 4 -8'

In [62]: [int(i) if rcomp.search(i) else i for i in str_.split()]
Out[62]: ['A', -3, 4, -8]
```

Comment: `'-1'.isdigit()` is false, though. `isdigit` doesn't fit the "test whether a string represents a number" use case as well as people keep expecting it to.

Comment: @user2357112 True. Edited to include some string matching with `re` instead of `str.isdigit`.

Comment: `i.strip('-').isdigit()` would also be an option to account for negative numbers.