# How can I check if a string is a number in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

In python.
If I have a string, how can I check if the string is a number or not?
`string1 = "1"` (True) or `string2 = "h"` (False) `string3 = "2g"` (False).
I tried to check if it is a letter but it doesn't work, the string also can be "," "." or " " and then it won't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using isdigit() method:

```
>>> a = "0123"
>>> a.isdigit()
True

>>> b = "012a"
>>> b.isdigit()
False
```