# Python guessing game - while loop to allow only whole numbers

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm building simple "guess number" game in python based on book "Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner: chapter 3". I can't figure out how to make this `while loop` part accept only whole numbers in `input`:

```
# Setting initial values
computer = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = input("Take a guess: ")
while guess != int or guess != float:
    guess = input("Use whole numbers: ")
tries = 1
```

The effect should be that after user types float or string program prints "Use only whole numbers".

After user types whole number it takes him out of the loop to the game:

```
# Guessing loop
while guess != computer:
    if guess < computer:
        print("You're bidding to low")
    else:
        print("You're bidding to high")

    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
```

I tried also, but it doesn't work either:

```
computer = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
while guess != int or guess != float:
    guess = input("Use whole numbers: ")
    if guess == int:
        break
tries = 1
```

Comment: You cannot compare a value for equality against a type (try `1 == int` and you will get `False`). Also, user input is always a string. For checking for integers, you can try [`isdigit`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) but that will fail on negative numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except which might actually have been a better target

Comment: Why not just convert the input to an int, `guess=int(input("guess a number"))`, that way it's always the correct type.

Comment: @user2699 because that will throw `ValueError` if they enter an input with a decimal point. You can wrap in a try/except to confirm that they entered an integer. Also, that's not the point of the exercise.

Comment: @roganjosh, I knew there was something I was overlooking.  A `try/except` block would be a good way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to cast your input to float and then use `is_integer()` to check if the input is an integer. However, if the input contains letters then it will raise a `ValueError` exception which you can handle to ask for whole numbers as input.

This would work for you:

```
while True:
    try:
        guess = input("Use whole numbers: ")
        if float(guess).is_integer():
            guess = int(guess)
            break
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(guess)
```

This would also work if the input is something like `123.0`.

Edited to address the comment regarding inputs like `1.000000000000000035`:

[image: Works for inputs like 1.0000000000000000000035]

Comment: Try it out, it wouldn't except `1.00000000000000000035` or even `1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035` .. I'll add a screenshot to show it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function for checking for a valid input:

```
def isInteger(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And modify your while loop like this:

```
while not isInteger(guess):
    guess = input()
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this would work for you, I am using python 2.7 and not much difference with the higher version

```
import random

def is_integer(num):
    try:
        num= int(num)
        return num
    except:
        False

def main(prompt, retries=5, complaint="wrong guess!!! try again..."):
    computer = random.randint(1, 100)
    while retries > 0:
        my_guess = raw_input(prompt)
        if is_integer(my_guess) == computer:
            print "Bingo!!! the answer is ",computer
            break
        retries = retries - 1
        if retries > 0:
            print "{} remaining {} tries left".format(complaint, retries)
        else:
            print "You are out of tries..."
            print "Exiting......."


main("please Guess a number? ")
```