# Convert given input from string to integer or float in python and if the input is string or character it can able handle it?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point, integer

inputs: `'aa'`, `'22'`, `'2.45'`

```
input ='22'
try:
   print int(input)
except ValueError:
   print float(input)
```

How to handle the above code when the input is 'aa' or 'example'?

Comment: another `try-except` inside your present `except` clause.

Comment: decide what you want to do with inputs like that. ignore them? skip them? then write an if condition around it.

Comment: why not simply convert all value to float rather than int and float and wrap around try catch block

Comment: Thank you  @Ev.Kounis --- It was easy and solved my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'aa'

try:
   print int(s)
except ValueError:
   try:
      print float(s)
   except:
      print 'its is a string'
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: This code handle string. the previous code does not allow characters or string.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest way to handle this is to check if the input string is numeric first:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

```py
if input.isnumeric():
    print int(input)
else:
    try
        print float(input)
    except ValueError:
        # Do nothing
```

However if you can avoid exceptions completely the code would be better - exception handling can be quite expensive.

This answer to testing for an integer explains why exception handling can be expensive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9859202/8358096

To avoid the second exception being hit regularly you could use the isalpha function mentioned below.

```py
if input.isnumeric():
    print int(input)
else:
    if not input.isalpha():
        try
            print float(input)
        except ValueError:
            # Do nothing
```

Comment: `'22.2'.isnumeric()` will return `False`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

The only time this breaks in cases like `input = 'a2'`.

```
inputs = ['aa','22','2.45']

for input in inputs:
   if not input.isalpha():
      try:
         print int(input)
      except ValueError:
         print float(input)
```