# How to check every input for isdigit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a game that generates a random integer and the user has to guess it.

The problem is that if the user input is not a digit it crashes. So I tried to use `isdigit`, and it works at the beginning, but if the user decides to input not a number after the first input was a digit, it still crashes. I don't know how to make it check `isdigit` for every input.

```
import random
x =(random.randint(0,100))
print("The program draws a number from 0 to 100. Try to guess it!")

a = input("enter a number:")
while a.isdigit() == False :
    print("It is not a digit")
    a = input("enter a number:")
if a.isdigit() == True :
    a = int(a)
while a != x :
    if a <= x :
        print("too less")
        a = input("enter a number:")
    elif a >= x :
        print("too much")
        a = input("enter a number")
if a == x :
    print("good")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please convert the screenshot of code to formatted code in your question.

Comment: on which line does code crash

Comment: The pythonic way to do that would be to simply try it and catch any exception, instead of double checking before attempting it. I.e. `try: a = int(a) except ValueError: # ask user again`.

Comment: @TalhaIsrar it returns "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zl.py", line 14, in <module>
    a = int(input("podaj liczbę:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
" when i type g

Comment: Its a simple error as you are trying to convert "g" which is a string to an integer which gives a value error

Comment: @TalhaIsrar i know, thats why i'm trying implement isdigit. if it will detect its not a digit it'll just tell that you have to input digit

Comment: Well, that error message you mention in the comment relates to code which is different from that in your post. Please check again which version of the code you are actually using.

Comment: @deceze sorry, but im newbie, could you be more specific where i should put this code? also, if i put in where i have a = int(a) it still gives me same error

Comment: @KamilKołodziej the way you are running your code is wrong. If you are using isdigit then why are you converting to int  a = int(input("podaj liczbę:"))?

Comment: @TalhaIsrar `cause it dont want to compare input if it's not a int as the generated number is. so i thought that is i convert it it will solve a problem

Comment: Of course it wont solve the problem instead it will create a new problem. if input is not an integer code will crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing the following:

```
completed = False
while not completed:
   a = input("enter a number: ")
   if a.isdigit():
      a = int(a)
      if a < x:
         print("too little")
      elif a > x:
         print("too much")
      else:
         print("good")
         completed = True
   else:
      print("It is not a digit")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code crashed because the user entered not a number, then either make sure the user enters a number, or handle an error while trying to compare it with a number.

You could go over all chars in the input and ensure that they are all digits.

Or you could use a `try/except` mechanism. That is, try to convert to the numerical type you wish the user to enter and handle any error throwen. Check this post:

[How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

And also:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: This is not the answer to the OP's question

Comment: @TalhaIsrar The post says: "i dont know how to make it check isdigit for every input."

Comment: This is still not the answer plz read the explaination. this should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

The typical pythonic way to tackle that would be to "ask for forgiveness instead of looking before you leap". In concrete terms, try to parse the input as `int`, and catch any errors:

```
try:
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Not a number')
```

Beyond that, the problem is obviously that you're doing the careful checking once at the start of the program, but not later on when asking for input again. Try to reduce the places where you ask for input and check it to one place, and write a loop to repeat it as often as necessary:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    except ValueError:  # goes here if int() raises an error
        print('Not a number')
        continue  # try again by restarting the loop

    if a == x:
        break  # end the loop
    elif a < x:
        print('Too low')
    else:
        print('Too high')


print('Congratulations')
```

Comment: Well, that sounds interesting. I'm a newbie so, could you explain to me what do you mean by ValueError? i'm opening a code in powershell so shall i just copy there a error that occurs?

Comment: You'll want to learn about handling exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# user vs randint

import random
computer = random.randint(0,100)
while True:
    try:
        user = int(input(" Enter a number : "))
    except (ValueError,NameError):
        print(" Please enter a valid number ")
    else:
        if user == computer:
            print(" Wow .. You win the game ")
            break
        elif user > computer:
            print(" Too High ")
        else:
            print(" Too low ")

I think this can solve the issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you want to check whether the user has input no or string since your not using int() in your input it will take input as string and furthur in your code it wont be able to check for <= condition

### for checking input no is string or no

code:-

```
a = input ("Enter no")
try:
   val = int(a)
   print("Yes input string is an Integer.")
   print("Input number value is: ", a)
except ValueError:
   print("It is not integer!")
   print(" It's a string")
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably will have to learn how to do functions and write your own input function.

```
def my_input(prompt):
   val = input(prompt)
   if val.isdigit():
      return val
   else:
      print('not a number')
      # return my_input(prompt)
```