# Python string 2d list to mixed int/string list

Tags: python, list, nested, mixed

Got this list:

```
test_list = [['1', '350', 'apartment'], ['2', '300', 'house'], ['3', '300', 'flat'], ['4', '250', 'apartment']]
```

Trying to get mixed list like

```
test_list = [[1, 350, 'apartment'], [2, 300, 'house'], [3, 300, 'flat'], [4, 250, 'apartment']]
```

So far my attempt:

```
res = [list(map(lambda ele : int(ele) if ele.isdigit()  
          else ele, test_list)) for ele in test_list ]
```

But doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `list(map(lambda`??? Use a list comprehension instead: `[[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in ele] for ele in test_list]` (using @eumiro's fixed version)

Comment: BTW `str.isdigit()` doesn't tell you if a string is a valid `int`. See for example [this answer and all the caveats and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265696/4518341). You should use a try-except instead if you're going to be handling anything else, even negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just a tiny problem with the variables.

In this fix, `test_list` is the whole list, `ele` is `['1', '350', 'apartment']` and `x` is one single string out of it.

```
[list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x, ele)) for ele in test_list]
```

but better use a list comprehension instead of `list(map(`:

```
[[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in ele] for ele in test_list]
```

Even better: a list of dicts or list of tuples would be more appropriate. A list is usually a collection of elements without specific role of each one of them.

```
[{'id': int(id), 'price': int(price), 'name': name} for id, price, name in test_list]

[(int(id), int(price), name) for id, price, name in test_list]
```

would also prevent you from converting a third item (name in my example) to integer if it was randomly called "123".

Answer (score 4):

Why use map if you already know the positions are correct for each sub-list

```
res = [[int(x), int(y), z] for x, y, z in test_list]
```

---

**Result**

```
[[1, 350, 'apartment'], [2, 300, 'house'], [3, 300, 'flat'], [4, 250, 'apartment']]
```

---

Or even better since this could be dict in the end use a dict comprehension:

```
res = {int(i): {'price': int(p), 'name': n} for i, p, n in test_list}
```

---

**Result**

```
{1: {'price': 350, 'name': 'apartment'}, 2: {'price': 300, 'name': 'house'}, 3: {'price': 300, 'name': 'flat'}, 4: {'price': 250, 'name': 'apartment'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test_list = [[int(ele) if ele.isdigit() else ele for ele in elem ] for elem in test_list]
```