# Getting Pygame keyboard input and check if it's a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to get keyboard input using Pygame using this command:

```py
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    # ADD KEYBOARD EVENTS
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
```

I want to check if the button pressed represents a number, I already know how to check if a string represent a number using `try/except` command, but, in my code `keys` is not a string, it is a huge tuple - and I don't know how to get it in an efficient way because every time I look in the internet on how to get keyboard input, they need to equate `keys` to something like `pygame.pygame.K_LEFT` and I don't want to do this for each number and furthermore every number in the number-pad (right side).

Is there an efficient way to determine if a user clicked on a number? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) returns a list with the state of all keyboard buttons. This is not intended to get the key of a keyboard event. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object:

```py
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_a:
        # [...]
```

`unicode` contains a single character string that is the fully translated character:

```py
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.unicode == 'a':
        # [...]
```

See also [pygame.key](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! It does work! Is there a way to check if a backspace is pressed using `event.unicode` ?

Comment: @StackOMeow a backspace can be recognized by `event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE` or `pg.key.name(event.key) == "backspace"`

Comment: I am trying `if event.type == pg.K_BACKSPACE and len(current_id) > 0:` below the `if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:` and it still does not work, assume current_id 's length is indeed bigger than 0 (I checked it) is it true how I wrote it? Thanks

Comment: @StackOMeow `event.type` -> `event.key`

Answer (score 0):

The following code offers quite a neat solution, it ignores all inputs that aren't numbers without even using try/except:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.unicode.isdigit():
    print(int(event.unicode))
```

I wasn't able to find a way to do this that was more compact on the web, so worked out this solution by researching how to check if a string is an integer.

[How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)