# Number guessing game with optional quit command

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, try-except

I'm trying to make a guessing game with the option for the user to quit the program, but I'm unable to get the 'quit' part of the program to work as intended.

```
from random import randint

userGuess = input("Pick a number from 1 to 1000: ")
guess = randint(1, 1000)
while userGuess != guess: 
    try: 
        userGuess = int(userGuess)
        if userGuess > guess: 
            print("The number you entered is higer than the guess. Try again.\n")
            userGuess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 to 1000: "))
        elif userGuess < guess: 
            print("The number you entered is lower than the guess. Try again.\n")
            userGuess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 to 1000: "))
        else:  
            print("You guessed it!")
            break
    except (TypeError, ValueError): 
        userGuess = str(userGuess)
        if userGuess.lower() == 'quit': 
            print("Quitting....")
            break
```

Whenever I run this program, if I type 'quit' when the game begins, it quits the program. However, if I guess a number before I type quit, the program goes through the if statements like it should, but when you try to quit after it just defaults, "the number entered is too low. try again" instead of quitting the program as intended.

I didn't know if there was a better way to handle the 'quit' command other than the try-except method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saint-jaeger beat me to the punch, the issue is indeed that you only ask for input again if the previous input was larger or smaller than the target number. If you enter 'quit' after having previously entered a number at least once, the `userGuess` still contains the previous number input.

Your code could be reorganized and simplified, which should make it easier to avoid these kinds of issues:

```py
from random import randint

target = randint(1, 1000)

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter your guess (between 1 and 1000), or "quit" to quit: ')

    if user_input.casefold() == 'quit':
        print('Quitting.')
        break

    try:
        user_guess = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Invalid input: {user_input}. Please try again.')
        continue

    if user_guess > target:
        print('Your guess is bigger than the number, try again.')
    elif user_guess < target:
        print('Your guess is smaller than the number, try again.')
    else:
        print(f'You guessed correctly, the number was {target}')
        break
```

Notice the amount of code under the `try` clause, which is only as big as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** In the line

```py
userGuess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 to 1000: "))
```

When you enter a number in the first place your userGuess is the number you have selected. Then you try to enter 'quit' , but the typecasting integer throws an error because it cannot do `int('quit')`. This causes the program to reach the `except:` part. However, you did not correctly change the userGuess value because of the error, and it is still the last number you have entered. This is why the `if userGuess.lower() == 'quit':`  condition never evaluates to True.

A simple fix would be taking the input first and tring to typecast later.

**EDIT:** As AMC pointed out the following part is wrong. It doesn't take into account that some unicode characters also return True for **isnumeric**, I was wrong. You can refer to [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) for ways to do this without try/except.

You can use the **isnumeric** function to check whether the input is an integer or a string.

```
user_input = input()
if user_input.isnumeric():
    #Do something
else:
    #Do something else
```

Comment: The fact that `str.isnumeric()` returns `True` doesn't mean that the string is valid input for `int()`. Also, I'm not sure how this is related to OP's question.

Comment: "Edit: If you are curious about what is wrong with your code" of course they are. That's the reason for asking a question.

Comment: @AMC You are correct. I just came up with an easy solution for a simple question without thinking about decimals or unicode. I will edit the post to reflect on that.
I just read the last paragraph and gave an answer to that, but I was mistaken.