# How to inform error when user leaving wrong format input?

Tags: python, if-statement, integer

How to inform error when user insert input which is not integer as requested?

For example:

```
number = int(input("Input the number: "))
```

I want to code something like: if number "is not" integer, so

```
if number is not integers 
            print("The input was not numerical value. Please try again")
        else:
            print ("Input "+ str(number) + " elements in the list:")
```

Can you help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of a non-integer that `int` could yield?

Comment: There have been already few posts about this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except

Comment: @ScottHunter you do not get my mean. For example: someone input character not integer for number so the system will print "The input was not numerical value. Please try again".

Comment: You do not get *my* mean: `number` has already been assigned the result of calling `int` before you can do any testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try/except statement should fit nicely:

```
try:
    number = int(input("Input the number: "))
    print ("Input "+ str(number) + " elements in the list:")
except ValueError:
    print("The input was not numerical value. Please try again")
```