# loop the list of substring and concatenate the elements that are digits together then renew the list

Tags: python, list

I wish to update the list such as below:

```
a = ['1-1-1,', 'market area,', 'destination,', 'power,', 'power', '-', '2', '234567', '90']
```

into

```
b = ['1-1-1,', 'market area,', 'destination,', 'power,', 'power', '-', '223456790']
```

What it does is actually to find elements in the list and if the next element is also digit then combine it. After combining all then reupdate the list as above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Comment: No, sorry. The case is differnet from mine but thank you.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: Actually, I know we can use isdigit to find he digit in subtring of list but I dont know how to combine it then update the list.

Comment: Ah, you should make it clearer in the question then what you do know and what you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we check if the element is digit using `.isdigit()`. If true add it to empty `conc` string, else check if any string is added to `conc`. If added append it to `b` list and empty `conc` string, else just add non-digit element to `b` list. Finally check whether `conc` string is empty or not. If not add it to `b` list.

```
a = ['1-1-1,', 'market area,', 'destination,', 'power,', 'power', '-', '2', '234567', '90']

b = []
conc = ""
for i in a:
    if i.isdigit():
        conc += i
    else:
        if len(conc) > 0:
            b.append(conc)
            conc = ""
        b.append(i)
# If string ends with digit, it will never perform else statement
# So need to add conc to b list after
if len(conc) > 0:
    b.append(conc)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is the one I am searching for.