# How to use two input types like str and int on one variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, integer

How can I input `int` or `string` from the user in **Python**.

```
user = input("Enter a number or name of person")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Answer (score 0):

```
user = input("Enter a number or name of person: ")
```

You want to check if it's an `int`?

```
user = input("Enter a number or name of person: ")
try:
    int(user)
except ValueError:
    # The type isn't int
```